# is picture in picture mode support on iPhone device for development purpose using swift?

Tags: swift, iphone

I have created one demo app for picture in picture mode. This app work on iPad device, but not work on iPhone device. Is there any solution for work on iPhone device?

Comment: No, you have to custom build it like Netflix and youtube

Comment: can you suggest any third party library for implement that custom

Comment: I don’t know of any, have a search on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

For `iOS13` and lower versions the answer is **No**, There is no such feature like PiP for iPhone with iOS 13 and lower versions. If you would like to build a PiP for your app then you have to build a custom.

With `iOS14` Apple has introduce pip for iPhone also.